# Selenium cannot find css/clasname selectors

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a small testing script for a website and as part of the test the program needs to click on butttons.
i'm using google chrome driver and i tried a few functions such as:
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector())
driver.findElements(By.xpath())
but the program doesnt recognize the locator for some reason.

[in the image i selected a button to get its id or class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaTlL.png)
(i'm sorry the website is in hebrew).

Main RunnerClass

```
 package runners;

 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

 import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
 import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)

 @CucumberOptions(features = { "src/test/java/featurefiles/" }, glue = {
    "stepDefinitions" }, monochrome = true, tags = {}, 
            plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", 
 "json:target/cucumber.json",

 "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html" })

  public class MainRunner {

}
```

Step Definitions Class

```
package stepDefinitions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;



 public class consumeSteps {

WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setup() throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
 Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toRealPath() +  
 "\\src\\test\\java\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, 
 TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


@After() 
public void tearDown() {
    this.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    this.driver.quit();
}


@Given("^I access pizzahut\\.co\\.il$")
public void i_access_pizzahut_co_il() throws Throwable {
    driver.get("https://pizzahut.co.il/");

}

@When("^I click on sales section button$")
public void i_click_on_sales_section_button() throws Throwable {
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("btn-default btn-block ng-binding ng- 
  isolate-scope")).click();

}

@When("^I click on add family non gluten pizza button$")
public void i_click_on_add_family_non_gluten_pizza_button() throws 
 Throwable {


}

@When("^I click on add button$")
public void i_click_on_add_button() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete 
 actions

}

@When("^I click on chosen extra$")
public void i_click_on_chosen_extra() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete 
 actions

}

@When("^I click on extra for the whole pizza$")
public void i_click_on_extra_for_the_whole_pizza() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete 
 actions

}

@When("^I click on choose and next button$")
public void i_click_on_choose_and_next_button() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete 
 actions

}

@When("^I click on continue for payment allert button$")
public void i_click_on_continue_for_payment_allert_button() throws 
 Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete 
 actions

}

@When("^I click on continue for payment button$")
public void i_click_on_continue_for_payment_button() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete 
 actions

}

@Then("^I should successfully be moved to the payment form$")
public void i_should_successfully_be_moved_to_the_payment_form() throws 
 Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete 
 actions

}



 }
```

Feature File

```
 Feature: consume product through sales section.

 Scenario: payment form will display after assembling a product.


Given I access pizzahut.co.il
When I click on sales section button
And I click on add family non gluten pizza button 
And I click on add button 
And I click on chosen extra
And I click on extra for the whole pizza
And I click on choose and next button
And I click on continue for payment allert button
And I click on continue for payment button 
Then I should successfully be moved to the payment form
```

Comment: The web site could be adding the content dynamically using its page script (lots of the modern sites do so). Try rechecking the element periodically in 100ms intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()=\"לכל המבצעים\"]")).click();
```

Comment: didnt work :(     
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()="לכל המבצעים"]"}

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
//div[@class='home-page-actions_promotion-btn']//a
```